# Using Google Forms how to make the menu item show multiple choice items not text items

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, google-sheets

I'm really new to all this.  I'm using a code for an add-on in google forms. I'm looking to change a few of the options to what suits my form better.

I want to make the menu item show multiple choice items not text items like it currently is showing.

```
    for (var i = 0; i < settings.textItems.length; i++) {
      var option = $('<option>').attr('value', settings.textItems[i]['id'])
          .text(settings.textItems[i]['title']);
      $('#respondent-email').append(option);
    }
    $('#respondent-email').val(settings.respondentEmailItemId);
  }
```